# Deserializing DataSet that contains 2d array with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I am trying to deserialize the below data to DataSet *(i believe DataSet is the right choice?)*. When my **data** **property** has **even** number of columns, it works alright, but when i have **odd** number of columns it throws: `Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object.`

**Request deserializing:**

```
        Stream inputStream = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream;

        inputStream.Position = 0;
        String json = new StreamReader(inputStream).ReadToEnd();
        inputStream.Close();

        System.Data.DataSet dataSet = null;

        dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Data.DataSet>(json);
```

**Mock data:**

```
var valid = 
{
    "colHeaders": [
        { "text": "TestHeader1", "influence": 1, "weight": 20.5 },
        { "text": "TestHeader2", "influence": 0, "weight": 30 }
    ],
    "rowHeaders": [
        { "text": "RowHeader1" },
        { "text": "RowHeader2" }
    ],
    "data": [
        ["data_00", "data_01"],
        ["data_10", "data_11"]
    ]
}

var not_valid = 
{
    "colHeaders": [
        { "text": "TestHeader1", "influence": 1, "weight": 20.5 }
    ],
    "rowHeaders": [
        { "text": "RowHeader1" },
        { "text": "RowHeader2" }
    ],
    "data": [
        ["data_00"],
        ["data_10"]
    ]
}
```

Comment: try creating your own class with List<List<string>> for data and List<Header> for headers etc. Because your JSON seems correct. Also the JSON worked for me with a Class

Comment: I am little hardcore... i want to spread my data by myself :D